# Why are my DVD and Bluray drives called /dev/srX? What does sr stand for?

Tags: devices

When I first started using Ubuntu, I *think* my CD drives were mapped through `/dev/cdrom0` and `/dev/cdrom1`, etc. but looking at things today, you can see they now come through on a `sr` prefix:

```
$ ll /dev/{cdrom,sr*}
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      3 Feb 10 09:15 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Feb 10 09:15 /dev/sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 1 Mar 27 10:30 /dev/sr1
```

I'm just curious what this stands for. [TLDP isn't being very helpful here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html); and it still lists `sd` as "SCSI drive", and I think it more commonly means "serial drive" these days.

What does "sr" stand for? Why does `/dev/cdrom` still exist?

Comment: As far as `/dev/cdrom` is concerned, I guess it exists only not to break any older programs or scripts that use it.

Answer (score 9):

> Linux **S**CSI **D**isk support module = **sd**_mod
>
> Linux **S**CSI **T**ape support module = **st**
>
> Linux SCSI CDrom support module = sr_mod
>
> Linux **S**CSI **g**eneric support module = **sg**

So, most likely, that stands for **S**CSI CD**r**om

[Source](http://www.ru.j-npcs.org/usoft/WWW/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO-6.html)

---

I've noticed that this doesn't fully address the question.

As you can see, `/dev/cdrom` is just a symbolic link to `/dev/sr0`, which is the actual device.

The naming of a character device is dependant on the module which initializes it: `SCSI` CD-ROMS are handled by the `sr_mod` module, and they're named after the module itself (`srX`).

If your CD-ROM drive happened to be an `IDE` drive, the actual device's name would have been `/dev/hdX`.

So since there are multiple interfaces through which a CD-ROM drive could be attached to the system, `/dev/cdrom` is used to always point to the first CD-ROM device (`SCSI`, `IDE` or whatever), most likely to give the drive an unique common interface for whatever needs to use it in the system.

> CDROM device names are not maintained by the uniform CDROM layer but rather by each individual protocol stack. In the case of the SCSI subsystem, device names are maintained by the sr driver while the IDE subsystem maintains device names with its central "ide" driver (i.e. not by the ide-cd driver). USB and IEEE1394 cd devices names are maintained by their respective stacks. This may partially explain why the /dev/cdrom is often a symbolic link to the appropriate subsystem's device name.

[Source](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/sr.html)

Comment: IDE drives are still named `/dev/sdX`, because `CONFIG_IDE` (giving the `ide-core` module) in Linux is deprecated in favor of `CONFIG_ATA` (libata-based driver), which makes most distributions choose the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/dnames.html), the letter `r` appears to derive from ROM. No further source is given however.